# Accessing a specific field in a list of lists - Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

My goal for this piece of a Prolog program I am working on is to access a particular field of a list of lists (containing a route's stopping points in a list followed by the distance of the entire route):

Here is the current format of my list of lists:

```
RoutesAndDistances = [[[Start, Stop1, Stop2, ..., End], TotalDistance],
                      [[Start, Stop1, Stop2, ..., End], TotalDistance]]].
```

How should I go about accessing the `TotalDistance` field of each record of `RoutesAndDistances`?

I know that, to access an individual field of a normal list, I would use Prolog's syntax of `[First | Rest]` to sort of peel away the list until the value of interest is reached,
but I don't know how to extrapolate this into a list of lists...

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your lists all seem to have exactly two elements, so you can say:

```
list_second([_,Second], Second).
```

and obtain the list of all distances with:

```
maplist(list_second, Routes_distances, Distances)
```

Note though that it makes little sense to use lists if you know beforehand that they all have only two elements. It is better to use structures instead, for example:

```
RDs = [route_distance([Start,Stop1,Stop2,...,End], D1),
       route_distance([Start,Stop1,Stop2,...,End], D2)].
```

This is a a lot more readable: Notice for instance that you already have one closing bracket too many in the example you gave.

It is easy to adapt the code to this representation:

```
rd_distance(route_distance(_,D), D).
```

and then:

```
maplist(rd_distance, RDs, Ds)
```

gives you the list `Ds` of all distances.

Answer (score 1):

That structure is a list of lists of pairs. [member](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2)/2 is the easier way to 'enumerate' elements of a list, on backtracking. Then pattern matching allows to extract the required field. For instance

```
?- member([_,X], [[[a,b,c],2],[[d,e,f],10]]).
X = 2 ;
X = 10.
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Would this member function also work on an arbitrary number of lists of pairs? If my whole list of pairs was called `LoP`, for example, could I call `member([_, X], LoP).`?

Comment: Yes, but beware you need to *backtrack* to access all elements, i.e. make Prolog work out *all solutions*, for instance with findall/3